# How to align a div with a buttons center to the logo on the left without using margin or padding

Tags: html, css

How can I align a div with buttons on the right center to the logo on the left without using margins or padding etc. You'll see what I mean if you check the images I've posted.

**Current Results**
[image: Current Results]

**Desired Results**
[image: Desired Results]

**My Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Logo </title>
    <style>

    #header {
        clear: both;
        margin: 0 auto 10px;
        padding: 0;
        position:relative;
        z-index:5;
        width:100%;
        background:#000;
        border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
        /*background: url("dark-noise-bg.png") repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);*/
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    }

    #head-content {
        width:1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 140px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .me {
    color: #333333;
    float: right;
    font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    margin-top:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;

}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
}

.logo {
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:0;

}

.logo img {
    margin: auto;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header" class="clearfix">

    <div id="head-content" class="clearfix">

        <div class="logo">
            <span><img src="http://localhost/wip/logo.png"></span>

        <div class="me">
            <button><span class="label">Publish</span></button>
            <button><span class="label">Preview</span></button>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why without margins or paddings?

Use `position: relative; top: 50px;`

**OR**

Use tables and `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: @justians Thanks for pointing me to the `table` approach. BTW... `pudding` :-) ?